# tornado shows me error 500 when run the app

Tags: routes, server, tornado

I set `LoginHandler` like this:

```
class LoginHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('admin/login.html',footertext='footer text goes here')
```

but it doesn't work.
I also change `static_url` to `static urls` in template, but still I have this.
Can somebody help me on this?

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1443, in _execute
>           result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/simon/myblog/handlers.py", line 53, in get
>           self.render('admin/login.html',footertext='footer text goes here')
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/web.py", line 699, in render
>           html = self.render_string(template_name, **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/web.py", line 806, in render_string
>           return t.generate(**namespace)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-4.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/tornado/template.py", line 345, in generate
>           return execute()
>
> File "admin/login_html.generated.py", line 13, in _tt_execute
>           _tt_tmp = _tt_utf8(True(_tt_tmp))  # admin/login.html:47 (via admin/framework.html:33)
>
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

what is the problem?

Comment: Looks like an error in your login.html, can you show the code around line 47 of login.html?

Comment: line 47 on login.htlm is nothing special but a div, i find in framework.html,for which i use for template,line 33 is {% block footer %},but i haven't put sth there.is it to be blame?

Comment: The starcktrace you enclosed show that the error is either in login.html or `BaseHandler` - show them.

Comment: `in BaseHandler:

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie("user")
    def write_error(self,status_code,**kwargs):
        self.render("404.html")`

Comment: @kwarunek is something wrong with write_error?

Comment: Edit your question with minimum working example - something I could run,  that we could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the pattern `_tt_tmp = _tt_utf8(True(_tt_tmp))` in the stack trace, I think you've set the `autoescape` variable to `True`, which is not a valid value. The `autoescape` setting must either be `None` or a function (the default is `xhtml_escape`). Since `autoescape` is on by default, you shouldn't need to set it at all; you only need to set it if you need to turn it off or use a non-default escaping function. If you do want to set it explicitly, set it to `xhtml_escape` since that is the default.

Comment: thanks ,i did set autoescape and now it works fine. :)